# What is the specific heat of steam, when Latent heat of vaporization decreases at the rate of $0.64 \:\rm Cal/K$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> specific heat of water at $100° C = 1.01\:\rm Cal/gm$ degree, latent heat of vaporization decreases at the rate of $0.64\:\rm  Cal/K$, latent heat of vaporization of $54\:\rm  C \:Cal/gm$. What is the specific heat of steam?

I am confused in the units given and I tried to solve it by comparing latent and specific heat to get $L = C\Delta T$, but unable to solve it, since I don't know what will be the temperature difference, Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Ok I will mark this. @EmilioPisanty

Comment: @sawankumawat, note that the capital "C" in calorie denotes a food calorie, which is 1000 "small" calories.  Small calories are denoted by a lower case "c".  The specific heat of water is 1 cal/gm-deg C, using the value of the small calorie.  The nomenclature matters, and mixing lower case and upper case letters becomes ambiguous.

Comment: Have you heard of Hess' Law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to the problem with units:

Specific heat should be in units of "calories/ gram/Celsius degree";

Latent heat of vaporization should be in "calories/gram" ;

Temperature change in Latent heat should be in "calories/gram/Celsius degree"

"calories" should be spelled here with a lower-case "c".  The capitalized version is $1000$ times bigger i.e $1$ Calorie is $1$ kilo-calorie.

There is a typo in the OP:  the latent heat of vaporization of water at $100 ^o$ C is $540$ calories/gram.

To solve the question, you should apply Hess's Law https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Thermodynamics/Thermochemistry/Hess's_Law%3A_The_Principle_of_Conservation_of_Energy

Simply put, *the energy change involved in going from A to B does not depend on the specific route you take*.

In this case:
First, take one gram of boiling hot liquid water, warm it *as liquid water* to $101^o$ C, and then vaporize it.  You have all the information needed to calculate  the energy needed to do this.

Secondly, take the same gram of boiling hot liquid water, vaporize it at $100^o$ C, and warm the resulting steam to $101^o$ C.  You have one unknown in the calculation of the energy needed:  the specific heat of the steam.

Set these two calculations equal (Hess's Law), and solve for the unknown.